# Android : Get Posts from Google Plus

Tags: android, google-plus

I have recently integrated Google Plus with my android app and it is working fine. Now i want to get all the posts, the signed in user shared. Is it Possible..?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check [the api docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list)? There is a page about getting the activities list, which may be what you are looking for.

Comment: This document is not for android. I simply require users all posts in android.

Comment: That document contains a Java example, which can be integrated with an Android app. You should make a HTTP request to the API server, collect data from the web service, then parse and use it. Also, please take a look at [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people). This is an implementation from the official api docs.